# Gzip file without changing inode

Tags: linux, gzip

I was wondering how I could gzip a file, without changing the i-node of the file that was zipped.

Comment: Since a new file is created, it would be exceedingly difficult to ensure that the old file is moved to a new inode, and that the new one placed at the former location.  How would you handle some other file getting dropped in that location between those two steps?

Comment: If what you mean is that gzip keeps the original file, my gzip version does not. gzip 1.3.12. I know zip does however actually create a new file and leaves the original untouched.

Comment: I meant exactly the opposite: `gzip` does not preserve the original after the new is written (notwithstanding `--keep`).

Answer (score 6):

Compress it into another file and then copy the contents over the original.

```
$ file=testfile1
$ ls -li $file
6630 -rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo 2075323 Nov  1 21:22 testfile1
$ gzip -c < $file > $file.tmp
$ cp $file.tmp $file
$ rm $file.tmp
$ mv $file $file.gz
$ ls -li $file.gz
6630 -rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo 8189 Nov  1 21:23 testfile1.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cp file /dev/shm ; cat /dev/shm/file | gzip > file ; rm /dev/shm/file
```

Comment: @StephenKitt If my interpretation is correct, this should work. It simply copies the file to a tmpfs, reads it out into gzip to compress, then fills up the existing file with the new compressed contents.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen you're right, the shell truncates the existing file so the inode doesn't change. Sorry Ipor!